# How to Repair/Rebuild .csproj File from Code files

Tags: c#, asp.net, svn, visual-studio-2010

I was working on a .Net 2.0 application. Late at night I upgraded it to .Net v.4. Then, as SVN was complaining I started to do manual conflict resolution. Even later than that I tried to check in my changes, then hit some conflicts so manually merged changes from the two different .csproj files.

I can't get back to where I was and rolling back to the previous version makes me lose all the code that has been written for it.

So I'm looking for a quick/dirty and reliable way of making sure my application code doesn't get lost?

Comment: "quick/dirty and reliable"? You know, those are mutually exclusive I think.

Comment: Making a local copy would qualify as quick/dirty, I guess.

Comment: Do as Rewinder says, cross your fingers and just hope you have not lost anything.

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping for more science and less superstition ('cross your fingers and just hope') than that, but I guess this is as good as it'll get ;-)

So I should make a copy of my code, and then manually add it, file by file to the project - is this what you all mean?

Comment: @Rewinder - it worked :)

Do you want to post your response as a 'formal' answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a quick and dirty solution, I would do the following:

- make a local (unversioned) copy of your working copy
- In visual studio, manually add each file to your project
- If you are **absolutely sure** you have not lost anything, and everything compiles, you can check-in your code

Comment: Thanks. Accepted.

PS. It was a bit of a leap of faith - I've never been "absolutely sure" of anything in my life :-(